# issue with texts and img alignment in the same div

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .floatright {
        float: right;
        width: 100px;
        margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    }
</style>
<div class="floatright">
    <img class="floatright" src="computer.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" /><br />
    Caption here
</div>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, </p>
```

Question:

If i remove this line:  `width: 100px;`, the text `Caption here` will not align with the left edge of img, why?

Comment: Hi i think you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohit_azad/X42y3/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because float is used with the element its width is compressed to allow other item to align with it and you are using 100px width the image is 100px too that y it will not align the caption under it but the paragraph text under div will align to it and ur alos using break tag after img there is no way caption text will align to img